# signalR startup configuration?

Tags: json, signalr, signalr-hub

I tried to inject a **signalr** into my asp.net mvc4 application. I did it successfully in webforms but here in mvc I got a runtime error during page load. I followed the same procedure as I did before that after you installed the signalr plugins it will give you a read me note about **startup.cs**.So I did my **startup.cs** something like this inside my Hubs folder and the rest of my hub classes:

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using MyMVCApp;

[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof(MyMVCApp.Startup))]
namespace MyMVCApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

and I also attached this scripts references in the view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Runtime Exception error:**
**Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

and it points on this line : **Line 21: WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);**

Are there still any configurations I missed? Thanks...

Comment: Do you have a reference to that assembly?

Comment: I'm not sure what assembly are you referring to? I thought after you installed the signalr into your project, you just have to typed in the script of your startup.cs and just referenced the three signalr plugins in your script at the view and you're good to go because that is what I saw in the video demo.

Comment: Newton.Json is installed along with signalr. I think I don't have a reference to that if that's what you're referring. Do I need to?

Comment: Does it affect since I have json result on my controller?